# hiragana / katakana / (kanji) hand-writing practice sheets

Tags: discussion, kanji, learning

I'm looking for hiragana / katakana hand-writing practice sheets for self-print.
Best would even be a template that can also be used for kanji.
Is there anything available?

You can find images on google image search but there are several problems with them. What I would need is:

1. first a square for each character divided in four sub-squares
2. this should later change to just one main square
3. continuously fading characters to write over (from very visible to hardly visible in one main square)
4. continuously size decreasing squares
5. maybe even a template to create and print yourself

Comment: You mean like [this](http://japanese-lesson.com/resources/pdf/characters/hiragana_writing_practice_sheets.pdf)? (https://www.google.com/search?q=hiragana+sheet+pdf)

Comment: Yes like this. Although this has the problem that there are no fading characters. They should fade until 3/4 of the row so the last 1/4 is for free writing.
You can find some with fading characters but then they either have a square with sub-squares or only one square not both like the one you linked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I guess that's a little over the top for now.